# No definitions matching so.cuo.platform admob.* could be found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I am trying to remote debug with FDB over USB and after I've compiled the app with amxmlc, I got the following errors:

```
No definitions matching so.cuo.platform admob.* could be found
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: IntroScreen_mc
...
```

My app uses admob extension, also in FlashDevelop after I compile the app there are no errors. I am using SDK 4.0 and all my swc libraries have been imported. I think there is something wrong with the paths but I don't know where to look.

Comment: check your import statement `so.cuo.platform admob.*`. Is it correct?

Comment: It is correct. I've even got code completion and can compile and run the app using FlashDevelop with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ,it a path error.

you not pack the ane lib realy ,you just packed the swc,so it work well when pack,but fail when run application.

how to fix?

right click your project in flash builder ,then set package option of ios or android.check up the check box under package option.